# MySQL - CSV UPDATE (not INSERT) into existing table?

Tags: mysql, csv

I have a table with the following columns:

```
id | name | city
```

The table has 1000 entries in it.

I have a CSV file with a limited number of lines like this:

```
id,city
34,Denver
45,Kansas City
145,New York
```

Can I use `LOAD DATA INFILE` to import my CSV into my table but instead of inserting new entries, it updates rows based off the `id` column?

Answer (score 7):

`REPLACE` mechanically runs `DELETE` and `INSERT`. That may change the PRIMARY KEYs.

Here is something else you can do.

Suppose your table is called name_city and it looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE name_city
(
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    city VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

and you want to do the `LOAD DATA INFILE`.

Here are your steps to update the city based on id:

Step 01) Create another table to use for the import

```
CREATE TABLE name_city_import LIKE name_city;
```

Step 02) Drop the name column from the import table

```
ALTER TABLE name_city_import DROP COLUMN name;
```

Step 03) Perform the import into `name_city_import`

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'somefile.csv' INTO TABLE name_city_import ...
```

Step 04) Perform an UPDATE JOIN

```
UPDATE name_city_import B
INNER JOIN name_city A USING (id)
SET A.city = B.city;
```

Step 05) Remove the import table

```
DROP TABLE name_city_import;
```

That's it.

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: Very cool, I didn't know that you could use a join like this. This was the perfect solution and kept my "A" database's primary keys in-tact. I could see how this may be a little bit more painful if you need to make updates across many columns, though.

Comment: this seems a bit of overhead because of the creating of the new tmp table , isn't there a way of doing bulk update directly from csv file if i have the entire row details ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have unique index on id or it's a primary key, you can add `REPLACE` : `LOAD DATA INFILE 'file_name' REPLACE ....`

Comment: How does this command know that the id field in the CSV file corresponds with the primary key id?